# Changing link suffix with javascript on keypress

Tags: javascript, html, image

I'm new to Javascript, so bear with me. Let's say I have this link: `example.com/img/000.png/`. It displays an image source, so I'll put it in an image tag. `<img src="example.com/img/001.png/">`.

When I press a key (`right arrow`, for example), the link should change (inside the image tag) to `example.com/img/001.png/`, `/002.png/`, `/003.png/`, etc. is is possible, at all, to do this with Javascript, embedded in the raw HTML?

Here are my thoughts so far:

```
<img src=" <!-- Link generated by Javascript --> ">
<script>
    // actually pythonic pseudocode, ok
    counter = 0
    if (right arrow key pressed):
        counter = counter + 1
        counterPrep = (3-len(counter))*'0'+str(counter) 
        // ^^^ changes the link from "1" to "001"
        link = "https://www.example.com/img/"+str(counterPrep)+".png
</script>
```

I know what I'm asking may be unclear, so feel free to ask questions. I usually work in Python, which is why the pseudocode is so "Pythonic".

Thanks!

Comment: Yep, only that you've to get familiar with [DOM Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect the key press of the user using the event called `keypress`.

The rigth arrow key has a key code 39, so you can do the following :

```html
<img src="example.com/img/001.png" id="myImage">
<script>
var counter = 0;
document.body.addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
   if(e.keyCode==39) {
      counter ++;
      var index = (("00" + counter).slice(-3));
      var link = "https://www.example.com/img/"+index+".png";
      document.getElementById('myImage').src = link;
   }
});

</script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `keydown` instead of `keypress`?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the snippet below:

```js
document.getElementById("testBtn").onclick = function() {
  var imgSrc = document.getElementById("dynamicImg").src;
  var start = imgSrc.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, end = imgSrc.lastIndexOf("/") + 4;
  var preUrl = imgSrc.substring(0, start);
  var postUrl = imgSrc.substring(end, imgSrc.length);
  // get the fileName
  var imgName = parseInt(imgSrc.substring(start, end)) + 1;
  // convert to 000 format
  imgName = ("00" + imgName).slice(-3);
  // replace img src
  document.getElementById("dynamicImg").src = preUrl + imgName + postUrl;
  alert(document.getElementById("dynamicImg").src)
};
```

```html
<img id="dynamicImg" src="example.com/img/000.png" />
<button id="testBtn">
TEST
</button>
```

The code above will work using dynamic url.
I tried it using onclick button, but you can change the event ti keypress.
I hope this helps.